# Initialize high dimensional sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to initialize `300,000 x 300,0000` sparse matrix using `sklearn`, but it requires memory as if it was not sparse:

```
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> sparse.rand(300000,300000,.1)
```

it gives the error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 671. GiB for an array with shape (300000, 300000) and data type float64
```

which is the same error as if I initialize using `numpy`:

```
np.random.normal(size=[300000, 300000])
```

Even when I go to a very low density, it reproduces the error:

```
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> sparse.rand(300000,300000,.000000000001)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py", line 842, in rand
    return random(m, n, density, format, dtype, random_state)
  File ".../lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py", line 788, in random
    ind = random_state.choice(mn, size=k, replace=False)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 980, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 4528, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.permutation
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 671. GiB for an array with shape (90000000000,) and data type int64
```

Is there a more memory-efficient way to create such a sparse matrix?

Comment: Where do you specify the density of the matrix population? As far as I can tell you are using the spares data structure on a non spares matrix.

Comment: @kpie `density=0.1`? the third parameter in `sparse.rand`. Even if you I go for less (e.g., density =0), it still gives the same error

Comment: `sparse.rand` is using `choice` to generate `k` random indices from a 300000*300000 integer space.  I often use this function to generate sample sparse matrix, but usually just for a reasonable test case like 10x10.  Clearly this isn't intended as a way of generating a very large matrix regardless of how sparse you make it.  The final matrix won't take up this much space, but this method of generating indices does temporarily need it.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` has various ways of creating sparse matrices.  A common on uses 3 `coo` style arrays - you could choose the index and data values of your choice.  A slower way is to start with a `lil` of the right shape, and "randomly" assign elements.  `sparse.random` is just a convenience tool for creating a test matrix, and rarely would be useful for production purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just generate only what you need.

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np

n, m = 300000, 300000
density = 0.00000001
size = int(n * m * density)

rows = np.random.randint(0, n, size=size)
cols = np.random.randint(0, m, size=size)
data = np.random.rand(size)

arr = sparse.csr_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(n, m))
```

This lets you build monster sparse arrays provided they're sparse enough to fit into memory.

```
>>> arr
<300000x300000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 900 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

This is probably how the sparse.rand constructor should be working anyway. If any row, col pairs collide it'll add the data values together, which is probably fine for all applications I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a reasonable `density` argument as seen in the docs... if you have like 10 trillion cells maybe like 0.00000001 or something...

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.rand.html#scipy.sparse.rand

Answer (score 0):

@hpaulj's comment is spot on. There is a clue in the error message also.

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 671. GiB for an array with shape (90000000000,) and data type int64

There is a reference to int64 and not float64 and a linear array of size 300,000 X 300,000. This refers to an intermediate step of random sampling in the creation of the sparse matrix, which occupies a lot of memory anyway.

Note that while creating any sparse matrix (irrespective of the format), you have to account memory for the non-zero values and for representing the position of the values in the matrix.